# Best way to split free text to items list python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a free text like `'2packetLays 1 liter milk 2loafsbrownbread2kgbasmatirice'` and want to split to below format - to separate out closely matched food items:

```
['2', 'packet', 'Lays', '1', 'liter', 'milk', '2', 'loafs', 'brownbread', '2', 'kg', 'basmatirice']
```

I was able to split above text to words like below:

```
['2', 'packet', 'Lays', '1', 'liter', 'milk', '2', 'loafs', 'brown' ,'bread', '2', 'kg', 'basmati', 'rice']
```

But I want `'brownbread'` as one word but I was getting as 2 different words:
`['brown' ,'bread']`

and `'basmatirice'` also as one word

Comment: You have to look for NLP package to solve this problem. Python `re` regex cannot do it.  There is no way to tell `brownbread` is really two words!

Comment: Do we have any packages available today to get all these food related items? I tried but was not able to get.